# WebApi2 CORS runs on IIS8 in Windows Server 2012

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors, windows-server-2012, iis-8

I can communicate with my CORS WebApi perfectly by access via different port numbers in my local IIS7.5 Windows7 server however once I deployed the code to the live server which is Windows 2012 server running IIS8 it returned "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present" error, are there some specific settings I need to configure for the live server which I did not require to on my local machine?

Comment: How did you register CORS? Did you add the live URLs to the Access-Control-Allow-Origin list?

Comment: Hi Alexander, what do you mean by register CORS?  I used the following code below in my WebApiConfig.cs var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("wildcard", "wildcard", "wildcard"); config.EnableCors(cors); this is going to be a public API once it is working, thanks.

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler I used the example in "http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api" which works fine in local but once I push it to live it longer works.

Comment: I tried that code on my local machine and on a IIS8/Windows 2012 Server. Works as expected. I also added some fake authorization which could potentially cause this issue. You can clone my complete sample from https://github.com/PDMLab/WebApiCorsSample. It also contains a sample for OWIN self hosting with CORS.

Comment: Hi Alexander & Brock, after a bit more investigation and played around with server environment I found out it is the Firewall which blocks the API domain so I could not access the data. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have WebDav enabled on the IIS8 server? It could be consuming the request and not making it to your Web API CORS code.

http://brockallen.com/2012/10/18/cors-iis-and-webdav/